# WordPress database error Duplicate entry '5.188.62.174' for key 'ip' for query INSERT INTO `wpop_loginizer_logs

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

```
[21-May-2023 03:03:29 UTC] WordPress database error Duplicate entry '5.188.62.174' for key 'ip' for query INSERT INTO `wpop_loginizer_logs` (`username`, `time`, `count`, `ip`, `lockout`, `url`) VALUES ('saqib', 1684638209, 1, '5.188.62.174', 0, 'https://scrapmycarservice.co.uk/xmlrpc.php') made by wp_xmlrpc_server->serve_request, IXR_Server->IXR_Server, IXR_Server->__construct, IXR_Server->serve, IXR_Server->call, wp_xmlrpc_server->wp_getUsersBlogs, wp_xmlrpc_server->blogger_getUsersBlogs, wp_xmlrpc_server->login, wp_authenticate, do_action('wp_login_failed'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, loginizer_login_failed, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew->insert, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->insert, W3TC\_CallUnderlying->insert, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew->insert, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->insert, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew->default_insert, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbNew->default_query
```

Error log displayed this error and I'm not able to log in to my admin dashboard
Does anyone know what to do??

I tried to deactivate the loginizer plugin from `cpanel` but it still not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There might be corrupted or duplicate entries in the wpop_loginizer_logs table. Consider backing up your database and then trying to clean up the table by removing any duplicate entries.